# Dropdown menu from mysql data

Tags: php, html, dropdown

I have this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'include/dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
header("Location: ../index.php");
}
$dropdown = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carros_real WHERE real_dono='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
while ($drop_row = mysql_fetch_array($dropdown)){
echo "<select>";
echo "<option value='".$drop_row['real_id']."'>" . $drop_row['real_marca'] .     "</option>";
echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

The Results are like this:
http://prntscr.com/9d1vpg

Well what i intend to do its the oposite...i need a list with all cars and i want to send the $drop_row['real_id'] to a $var.
What i am missing here?
Thanks

Comment: move your `<select>` and `</select>` out side of your while loop

Comment: Thank you... but... can you please do an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'include/dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: ../index.php");
}
$dropdown = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carros_real WHERE real_dono='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
  echo "<select>";
while ($drop_row = mysql_fetch_array($dropdown)){

echo "<option value='".$drop_row['real_id']."'>" . $drop_row['real_marca'] .     "</option>";

 }
 echo "</select>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Upvoted!
That did the job perfectly.
Now i can insert it on a form and get $_POST['name_here'] right?

Comment: This could lead to SQL injection vulnerability if you made a mistake in some place. Escape `$SESSION['user']` just to be safe.

Comment: Or better yet, switch to `mysqli_` or PDO, and use prepared statements! :-)

Comment: Just one more question... how do i assign the selected option value to a $var to use if($_GET['option']){} i tried to insert a name='car' and assign it to do $var = $_GET['car']; but that did not work. thanks